# pass variables for import_from_git

Tags: ios, jenkins, fastlane

I want to have a generic Fastlane file for my projects. In each project, I just want to set some Variables that the general files needs.

I imagine the custom Fastfile should look something like this:

```
myVariable = "Tank"
myArray = ["1", "2", "3", "let's go"]
import_from_git(url: 'git@github.com:foo/FastlaneFiles.git', path: 'Fastfile')
```

But, this wont work, I think it expects the definitions to be in a lane. How do I have to define the variables, so that the generic Fastlane can use them? (I'd prefer not setting environment variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the trick, when your Fastfile is being run, `self` is a Ruby `Fastfile` instance. So, that means you can simply add an instance variable in place:

```
@myVariable = "Tank"
@myArray = ["1", "2", "3", "let's go"]
```

And that will be available to your other Fastfile that was imported as instance variables `@myVariable`.